# Python: Create numpy array between two dates

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

Trying to create an array from a startdate to an enddate with a slot for every second. Pretty much like `numpy.linspace(startdate,enddate,number_of_seconds_inbetween)`. Whats the easiest/fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def linspace_datetime64(start_date, end_date, n):
    return np.linspace(0, 1, n) * (end_date - start_date) + start_date
```

Example usage:

```
>>> start_date = np.datetime64('2008-01-01')
>>> end_date = np.datetime64('2009-01-01')
>>> linspace_datetime64(start_date, end_date, 12)
array(['2008-01-01', '2008-02-03', '2008-03-07', '2008-04-09',
       '2008-05-13', '2008-06-15', '2008-07-18', '2008-08-20',
       '2008-09-23', '2008-10-26', '2008-11-28', '2009-01-01'],
      dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: The answer is not complete. It doesn't show how to get *every second* between any two dates.

Answer (score 5):

`np.arange` does it more or less out of the box:

```
np.arange("2000-01-01","2000-01-02",dtype="M8[s]")
# array(['2000-01-01T00:00:00', '2000-01-01T00:00:01',
#        '2000-01-01T00:00:02', ..., '2000-01-01T23:59:57',
#        '2000-01-01T23:59:58', '2000-01-01T23:59:59'],
#       dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

Comment: Ah nice... didn't think this was possible directly using `np.arange`

Comment: Now the question is why there isn't a `np.linspace` implementation for this. XD

Comment: linspace produces evenly spaced floats. The datetime steps are discrete - days, minutes etc

Comment: @hpaulj `linspace` can output "exact" dtypes like `int`, so in principle it should be possible to make `datetime64` work in the same way.

Comment: `linspace` is Python code.  The current `linspace` (1.16) works by creating a `arange(N)` and scaling with the end points (which may be arrays).  Math with `datetime64` is limited to subtraction.  But `np.array("2000-01-01",'M8[D]') + np.linspace(0, 10, 11).astype("timedelta64[D]") ` does work.